War Magic feature with a Heavy Crossbow
In the new 2024 rules, the Eldritch Knight 7th level feature "War Magic" states:

When you take the Attack action on your turn, you can replace one of the attacks with a casting of one of your Wizard cantrips that has a casting time of an action.

If you use a Heavy Crossbow, even though you can only fire it once, can you then use your other attack to cast a Cantrip?

Yes. Loading only limits how many bolts you can fire
The Loading property of the Heavy Crossbow (p. 214 PHB) says:

You can fire only one piece of ammunition from a Loading weapon when you use an action, a Bonus Action, or a Reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

This does not reduce the number of attacks you can normally make, it just limits the number of pieces of ammunition you can fire from the weapon. So, you can still use the remaining attacks to do something else, such as casting a cantrip with War Magic.
Note however that the Heavy Crossbow is Two-Handed, too, so if you need a free hand for your spellcasting, you would need to "unequip" the crossbow (as part of your Attack action after the crossbow attack, see "Attack [Action]" in the Rules Glossary on p. 361 PHB) before you can cast the cantrip.

Did the two-handed property change in 2024, so it's no longer sufficient or possible to just take one hand off a 2H weapon for free in order to cast spells?  In 2014, you needed two hands to attack with a 2H weapon, but only one to simply hold it.  (If that is still allowed, the OP's plan is a great way to defer taking Crossbow Expert until Two Extra Attacks (11th level) without wasting attacks; you can draw+throw a dagger if silenced or your cantrips would be bad choices.  Or if you never take xbow xpert, could switch to longbow at 11th level.)

@PeterCordes AFAIK, the rules have not changed on that topic. The 2024 rule says: "Two-Handed. A Two-Handed weapon requires two hands when you attack with it."
